# how to check if a table has any recoeds with dexie js in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am using dexie Js to use indexedDb. I have created a table like below with a service that I have created for dexiService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import { UserModel } from 'src/app/models/user/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DexiedbService extends Dexie {
  public user: Dexie.Table<UserModel, number>;
  constructor() {
    super('shDb');
    this.version(2).stores(
      { user: "++id,token,name,lastName,img" }
    );
    this.user = this.table("user");
  }
}
```

later I save a row into the db and my problem is that I want to check if there is any value (rows) in the created table. I have tried this:

```
  isUserLoggedIn() {
    const users = this.dexiDb.user.mapToClass(UserModel);
    if (users.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

but the problem is that the `users` `const` is just an instance of my class and does not show any content. any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using the [count()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.count()) function, which can also be combined with `where` conditions. Performance information can be found in the official doc behind the above link.

On a side note: I wouldn't store the current user in an indexedDB table. I'd say session-/localStorage combined with an rxjs subject would be a more flexible fit, to make sure you don't have duplicate user sessions and are able to propagate user state to multiple components easier.